# What to include in software metric calculation on laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, metrics

Laravel project contain a lot of files and folder.
When we are calculating the Software Metric, should we include them all?
I am using [phpmetric](http://www.phpmetrics.org/) but it ignored the vendor folder.
But when I use [phpdepend](http://pdepend.org/) , it included that folder.
Thanks.

Comment: Basically everything under `/app` is your project, so that's what you should be measuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're measuring, which is why there's no one answer and similar tools may, or may not, include the `vendor` folder.

If you're interested in the analyzing your own project, then you'll want to point these tools at files **you'll** be editing. In Laravel 5 that mostly means the `app` folder -- but you might want to include `config` and `bootstrap`, as user created code often finds its ways in those folders.

A reason you might point it at `vendor` is if you were concerned about the direction a particular code library you use is going, and wanted to measure it over time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well yeah basically it's everything that we code right? but do you have a scientific reference about that? It's for my school work, because I can't just said "because some random people on stackoverflow said so"., hehe

Answer (score 0):

vendors (external code) is not important for you. When you measure your project, you should measure YOUR code only:

- vendors **are already tested / measured in their own repository**
- if you include external librairies, **you don't measure your work**
- your should exclude **generated files** (cache...). They are not representative of your work
- you should exclude **test files** : they do not obey the same quality rules

If you want to get information about a particular code library you use, you can check the Github repository of this library. There is a [list of PhpMetrics representations of main PHP projects](https://peteraba.com/blog/phpmetrics-of-popular-projects/), you can also keep on eye on it.